# Print in HTML an icon + a variable + a string with Vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a function that should return this:

```
<i class="fas fa-check-double"></i>' + lastMessageShort + '...'
```

Where lastMessageShort is value from an array of objects.
In HTML everything worked until I've tried to print the icon.
In HTML the portion of code that prints is this:

```
<div class="chat-preview">
   {{ getLastMessage(index) }}
</div>
```

The function takes the index from a previous v-for, but this part works fine.
So how can I print an icon in HTML along with the other elements? I've also tried template literal with no results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to output dynamic HTML, you can use [v-html of vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html)

Here is a simple example of your code:

```
getLastMessage(index) {
        let lastMessageShort = 'hi there' + index
        return `<i class="fas fa-check-double"></i> ${lastMessageShort}`
      }
```

In HTML template like this:

```
<div class="chat-preview">
    <span v-html="getLastMessage(2)"></span>
  </div>
```

Just use any tag that inside you want to wrap your dynamic HTML, and then call your function to return it inside `v-html`.

Comment: how could i embed this: <v-icon>mdi-menu</v-icon>